# Laravel get div without ajax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Hi I am trying to get the content within a div element that also happens to be within a form into my controller. I dont want to use ajax. How may I get that done ?

```
 <div id="editorcontents" name="editorcontents">
 </div>
```

Then in controller

```
  Use Input;
  $content = Input::get('editorcontents');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, do something like this. Look up the correct way in the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models). For example, if you want ALL input, you would do `Input::all();`, instead of `Input::where('editorcontents')->get();`

```
public function index() {

    $content = Input::where('editorcontents')->get();

    return view('your_view.blade.file', compact('content'));
}
```

Then in your view your would now have `$content`, that you passed from your controller.

start of by looking at it, add this at top of your view: `{{ dd($content) }}`. This will `die dump $content`.

Go ahead and remove that line and do something like (docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops):

```
<div id="editorcontents" name="editorcontents">
  @forelse ($content as $value)
      <li>{{ $value->body }}</li>
  @empty
      <p>No content</p>
  @endforelse
</div>
```